# Meta-Tags Extractor

Tags: meta-tags

I have a website and I have added meta tags for both Keyworkds and Description. They appear when I view the source of the site, but when I use any Meta Tag Extractor tool it says

> No Meta Tags found on the given address.

Can anyone shed some light as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we found the issue it was website issue which was crashing internally and causing blank response from the Meta Tag Extrator tools. Thanks.